# Can Ridged Bodies from Blender animation remain after animation loops in Unity?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, unity

I have created a keyframe animation in Blender for a pistol firing. The shell cases eject and at the apex of their ejection, a ridged body is applied that uses the trajectory to finish off the motion.

Is there a way to replicate this ridged body object so it remains in the scene every time the animation is played in Unity ?

New to animating and unity so not sure if this is even a correct practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to bake the simulation

Comment: I understand baking as a concept, but will that not result in the same result each time ?, The reason for adding the ridged body to the shell casing was to allow it to interact with game world realistically, Will baking the simulation now restrict this ?